# scrollview doesn't show with autolayout [MASONRY]

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm having a scrollview with a textview in it like this:

```
UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] init];
text.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac porttitor diam, sed facilisis odio. Donec hendrerit augue a tempor tincidunt. Vestibulum est arcu, dignissim vel metus eu, eleifend dictum libero. Donec eu lacus at elit iaculis cursus. Donec aliquam sem felis, eget cursus nibh viverra in. Quisque cursus orci commodo hendrerit scelerisque. Donec at elementum massa. Donec euismod imperdiet libero, id varius tortor finibus tempor. Praesent vel varius nibh. Nunc sagittis urna vel augue ornare, eu laoreet mi pretium. Fusce imperdiet enim sed sodales eleifend. Donec sit amet ultricies elit, sit amet suscipit sapien. Vivamus bibendum mi turpis, elementum gravida metus egestas sed. Donec et justo interdum, iaculis sapien eget, volutpat ipsum. Phasellus libero nisl, pretium tincidunt ligula non, rutrum tempor metus. Pellentesque rutrum sapien non libero pharetra, ut porttitor eros finibus. Curabitur tincidunt convallis risus eu porta. Fusce ac pulvinar lectus. Praesent quam lacus, feugiat ac ligula aliquet, tempor cursus ante. Ut sit amet sodales odio. In commodo fringilla felis ac faucibus. Quisque tempor urna ligula. Curabitur consectetur a elit at condimentum.";

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView addSubview:text];

[scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
}];

[text mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(scrollView);
}];
```

The scrollview is as big as the screen ( checked it with iOS 8 hierarchy inspector ). But the TextView isn't showing unless I add a constraint in the text mas_make.. like for example make.width.and.height.equalTo(@100). Then it is showing but this isn't the way I think.

Why is the textView not showing? Because I explicit say make left,right,top,bottom equal to scrollview and the scrollview is as big as the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by changing the TextView to a Label. Like this:

```
UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] init];
text.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ac porttitor diam, sed facilisis odio. Donec hendrerit augue a tempor tincidunt. Vestibulum est arcu, dignissim vel metus eu, eleifend dictum libero. Donec eu lacus at elit iaculis cursus. Donec aliquam sem felis, eget cursus nibh viverra in. Quisque cursus orci commodo hendrerit scelerisque. Donec at elementum massa. Donec euismod imperdiet libero, id varius tortor finibus tempor. Praesent vel varius nibh. Nunc sagittis urna vel augue ornare, eu laoreet mi pretium. Fusce imperdiet enim sed sodales eleifend. Donec sit amet ultricies elit, sit amet suscipit sapien. Vivamus bibendum mi turpis, elementum gravida metus egestas sed. Donec et justo interdum, iaculis sapien eget, volutpat ipsum. Phasellus libero nisl, pretium tincidunt ligula non, rutrum tempor metus. Pellentesque rutrum sapien non libero pharetra, ut porttitor eros finibus. Curabitur tincidunt convallis risus eu porta. Fusce ac pulvinar lectus. Praesent quam lacus, feugiat ac ligula aliquet, tempor cursus ante. Ut sit amet sodales odio. In commodo fringilla felis ac faucibus. Quisque tempor urna ligula. Curabitur consectetur a elit at condimentum.";
text.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView addSubview:text];

[scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self.view);
}];

[text mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.width.equalTo(scrollView);
}];
```

Then it works.